# sem() function Error in w_mat %*% p_deriv_mat %*% invMat

Tags: r, structural-equation-model

I ran into the following error when running the sem() function:

I have just ran this code using a different syntax and it worked; so I know the problem should be either in the way I loaded the factors to the syntax... or a typo?

```r
library(psych)
library(sem)

#Creating syntax equation
mgb_syn_eq <- "
MIL: S.Defense                        #Military and National Security
GOV: E.GovLess, E.GovFM, E.GovBig     #Limited Government
BUS: E.BusinessReg                    #Business
"
#Creating CFA Syntax from theory
mgb_syn <- cfa(text = mgb_syn_eq, reference.indicators = FALSE)

#Use the sem() function to run a CFA
mgb_CFA <- sem(mgb_syn, data = df.secs_CFA)
```

Error in w_mat %*% p_deriv_mat %*% invMat : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Comment: Include the packages you used in the code, or it's not reproducible.

Comment: Is this the `lavaan` package?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

The problem was that psych package only has some of the basic functions of the lavaan package AND that I was trying to estimate a latent value with only 1 parameter (you need at least 3).